# Recursive mixin gives error after one loop

Tags: css, recursion, sass, scss-mixins

I'm wondering what exactly is wrong with my recursive mixin.

```
@mixin backgroundPosition($x, $limit) {
    $temp: #{$x * 32};
    background-position-x: -#{$temp} +px;
    $num: #{$x + 1};

    @if ($limit < 10) {
        & > * {
            @include backgroundPosition($num, $limit + 1)
        }
    } 
}
```

Ideally, I want something that goes

```
background-position: -32px;
    & > * {
        background-position: -64px;
        & > * {
            background-position: -96px;
            ...
        }
    }
```

So, I include it...
`@include backgroundPosition(1, 1);`

However, codepen will give me this error:

```
Error: Undefined operation "2 * 32".
╷
21 │ $temp: #{$x * 32};
│ ^^^^^^^
╵
pen.scss 21:12 backgroundPosition()
pen.scss 27:7 backgroundPosition()
pen.scss 40:5 root stylesheet
```

Showing `"2 * 32"` means my mixin goes through the first time, but once it goes through one recursion loop it somehow breaks, and I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was using interpolation wrong all along. My bad.
Here's the correct way to calculate the values I needed. (Yes, the compiled css does look a bit terrible)

```
@mixin backgroundPosition($x, $limit) {
    $temp: calc(#{$x} * 32px * -1);
    background-position-x: #{$temp};
    $num: calc(#{$x} + 1);
    @if ($limit < 10) {
        & > * {
            @include backgroundPosition($num, $limit + 1)
        }
    }

}
```